# Delete cell and adjacent value in Excel, but keep the largest number

Tags: excel, subroutine

Here's an example of the Excel table I've got:

```
1631823842  1
1631823842  2
1631823842  3
1631823853  1
1631823853  2
1631823859  1
1631823859  2
1631823859  3
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to delete all the duplicates EXCEPT the largest. So I'd be left with:

```
1631823842  3
1631823853  2
1631823859  3
```

How can I accomplish this with Excel?

Attempt, but i'm not sure what the command is for multiple columns. Tried A:B and A,B. Pretty sure I = 2 is correct.

Here it is:

```
Sub sclera()

Dim lastRow As Long
e = 1

With ActiveSheet

lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A:B").End(xlUp).Row 

For I = 2 To lastRow 

If Left(.Cells(I + 1, 1), 10) <> Left(.Cells(I, 1), 10) Then
    .Cells(e, 2) = .Cells(I, 1)
    e = e + 1
End If

Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Are those in one column or two?

Answer (score 3):

This assumes your data is all in one column.

```
Sub sclera()

Dim lastRow As Long
e = 1

With ActiveSheet

    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'assuming your data is in column A

    For I = 1 To lastRow 'assuming it starts on row 1

    If left(.Cells(I + 1, 1), 10) <> left(.Cells(I, 1), 10) Then
        .Cells(e, 2) = .Cells(I, 1)
        e = e + 1
    End If

    Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the quick response, it's in A and B, with the UPC in A and the quantity in 2. It also has headers.

Comment: So modify the code to suit your needs. I did 99% of the work.

Comment: Trying my best as we speak, but doesn't having another column with tied-in data change everything?

Comment: Post the code of what you're trying. `change everything`? Uh, no. And the logic (the most valuable part) certainly doesn't change.

Comment: Edit your OP instead.

Comment: There is no last column command. I didn't reply because you didn't try anything. You have no understanding of what my code is doing. I have no patience for those that do not try.

Comment: You're right, I have no understanding of Excel or coding, I said that from the very beginning. I've found someone from another community that solved it. I'll be Paypaling them (all I wanted it was solved), and never returning here.

Comment: lol yea, I am doing this for money. That's why this is freelance.com lolol

Answer (score 0):

Since you dont put any code, i answer in the same way :P Just compare each number with next one, if they are equal, check second number and delete the lowest